# Unauthorized error on push request for issue openwisp/openwisp-notifications#6

Tags: openwisp

I have resolved the issue: [openwisp/openwisp-notifications#6](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-notifications/issues/6) from project [openwisp-notifications](https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-notifications). But I am not authorized to push to create a pull request since I am getting an error of HTTP 403. So I was hoping if anyone could help me out.
Error:

```
remote: Permission to openwisp/openwisp-notifications.git denied to RithikBanerjee.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/openwisp/openwisp-notifications.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fork the project, commit to your own fork and send a pull request from there.

Comment: Absolutely. Got it.